# SQL Select query where column like string with and without spaces

Tags: php, sql

I have a SQL Select query in PHP where i need to lookup rows in a table where a column is like a string with and without spaces

for example, if my value in the database is `ABC 123` and i search for `ABC123` the query will be

```
$sql = SELECT * from table where col_name LIKE '%ABC123%' ";
```

but i need it to return the row where col_name equals ABC 123

and vice versa, for example, if the database value is `123ABC` and i search for `123 ABC` the query will be

```
$sql = SELECT * from table where col_name LIKE '%123 ABC%' ";
```

and i need it to return the row where col_name equals `123ABC`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$sql = SELECT * from table where REPLACE(col_name,' ','') LIKE '%ABC123%' ";
```

Comment: how about the vice versa ?

Comment: select * from table where replace(col_name,' ','') = replace('ABC 123',' ','')

Comment: $sql = SELECT * from table where REPLACE(col_name,' ','') LIKE '%123 ABC%' ";

Comment: @user2710234:Its just the same .It`s all about the replace function